# C - Loop, <math.h>, and float

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int result;
    float f;

    while((result = scanf("%d", &i)) != EOF)
    {
        scanf("%f", &f);
        printf("%.0f %.0f %.0f\n", floor(f), round(f), ceil(f));
    }
    printf("Done.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Hi,

I just began with C and I'm having a problem solving a question.

The problem is that with the user input, I need to get three sets of numbers that are floored, rounded, and ceiled. This process must be ongoing until the user stops by EOF command (Ctrl-D).

When I run my code above, input a value 3.1415, I get 0 0 1 as an output, which is wrong because it's supposed to be 3 3 4.

Any suggestions or help on how to fix the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: What about `scanf("%d", &i)`? did you input the integer?

Comment: You have to add details of how to reproduce the error, because this program prints 3 3 4 for the input 3.14.

Comment: weird way for checking EOF.scanning input twice? how give input? can you show it? why not check for one scanf and if not EOF then print else whatever

Comment: use fgets() instead to read the line from the keyboard, then use sscanf to parse the line. e.g. `while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL) {...}`

Comment: My suggestion would be to split the problem int smaller parts. First, check that you are reading in the numbers as you expect. Separately, check the `printf` with a fixed, correct number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your code, you first need to input an integer value and then enter a `float` value.

OR, you can start accepting `float` value like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int result;
    float f;

    while((result = scanf("%f", &f)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%.0f %.0f %.0f\n", floor(f), round(f), ceil(f));
    }
    printf("Done.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now I get what the problem was.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to your code **you need to input integer first then float**, But if you enter float value first, that value read by `i` first and return 0 that is `!=EOF`, so second `scanf` does not wait for input, because it is inside the `while` loop. So always you will get `0 0 1` for all inputs!

To scan a number inside while loop use-

```
 if (scanf("%f", &f) == 0) {
  printf("Err. . .\n");
  do {
    c = getchar();
  }
  while (!isdigit(c));
  ungetc(c, stdin);
```

Else scan `float` value first instead of `int` and `float`. Try this code-

```
while((result = scanf("%f", &f)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%.0f %.0f %.0f\n", floor(f), round(f), ceil(f));
}
printf("Done.\n");
```